# How to send Stripe's test webhook for other customers?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, webhooks

I'm trying to test Webhook events for different customers.  The problem is the request stripes test webhook is always sending cus_00000000. (That  is for default customer).

I have different test customers and subscription in my account. Now I want to send test webhook for particular customer. It is sending request as following-

[image: Testwebhook request snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

The test webhook button will by default send with `cust_0000000`

In order to test for a particular customer, what you can do is to perform the operation under `Test Mode`

In your screenshot, you are handling the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event. what you need to do is to create an invoice and pay the invoice on your dashboard

In your dashboard, `Billing` > `Invoices` > `New` > `Select Customer` you want to test against > `Automatically charge customer by the source` > `Send invoice`

An invoice should be sent and paid, you should be able to capture the webhook event.